C++ Program calling "Entry Point Not Found" on executable file
I'm a beginner programmer learning C++ using Bjarne Stroustrup's book "Programming Principles And Practices" [2 Edition]. There is a program I wrote for a simple calculator that just reads an expression and thus calculates the output [The program doesn't follow BODMAS just yet, that is because the chapter I'm on is teaching iterative development]. Also, I'm using the facilities header as the book wants followed. Here is the program:
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {

    double current;
    double next;
    char op;

    cout << "Expression: ";

    cin >> current;

    while (cin >> op >> next) {

        switch (op) {

            case '+':

                current += next;
                break;

            case '-':

                current -= next;
                break;

            case '*':

                current *= next;
                break;

            case '/':

                current /= next;
                break;

        }

    }

    cout << "Expression evaluates to: " << current;
    return 0;

}


a
The program compiles without error, however when calling the '.exe' file from the command prompt, I encounter 'Missing Entry Point' error.
The error reads:
The procedure entry point _ZNKSt9basic_ioslcSt11char_traitscEEcvbEv could not be located in the dynamic link library [My program's address].
I inferred that the error is on my laptop specifically because I copied the program on another laptop where it ran fine [It compiled and executed as expected]. I also found elsewhere that a "
sfc /scannow" command would help with DLL errors however on completion the error persists. Lastly, a user's answer for another question on Stack Overflow here pointed out that adding two parameters to the compile command worked removed the error. That did work for me, but I wished to know what was the cause of the problem, which that user did not explain or why the conventional compile command isn't working.
I'm using a Windows 10 OS on a HP Probook
The added parameters that worked were: -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
I added this to my original compilation line: "g++ "First Design.cpp" -o "First Design.exe"
[The name of my program is "First Design"]
Thanks for atleast reading my question!

please specify the operating system and IDE & compiler that you are using first. that an entry point is not found indicates that when you call the program, it does not know the name of the function to call first. typically that is something you tell the linker.

[Edit] your question with your compilation line, and specify what the extra parameters that fixed your issue.

This means you have DLL Hell

command would help with DLL errors It helps in the case of your OS filesystem somehow gets corrupt dlls. That's not likely the problem here.

I inferred that the error is on my laptop specifically because I copied the program on another laptop where it ran fine This is your big mistake. Don't do that.

The error is that you copied your program, not with your laptop. If you had built the program on your laptop there would be no problems. If you want to learn how to build programs so that they will not have this problem then you need to look at statically linking your programs with the C++ runtime. Consult your compilers documentation, or this answer may be relevant (assuming you are using Microsoft's compiler).

@AndersK I'm using atom, not an IDE I suppose. I installed my compiler using MSYS, which was specified in a visual studio 'Getting Started Post'. I feel as a beginner I should first program in a raw text editor before delving into IDE's. I'm using my command line to compile.

@StephenNewell Done as asked.

@drescherjm Err, how to get out of that 'hell'?

@john Are the two parameters [They technically are flags I feel], I edited to my question related to this linking? Also, why isn't it linking successfully without those?

@AryanJha Yes those are the two flags that use static linking for g++ (but I'm no expert on g++). The two alternatives are static lining and dynamic linking, with dynamic linking being the default. Dynamic linking links with dlls present on the machine you are building on. The issue then is that any machine you copy to must have the same dlls with the same version number. One way to ensure that is to copy the dlls along with your program. With static linking the executable is larger but also self-contained.

@john Okay, that helps a lot. Thank you. I was stuck on this for a long time.

your program is likely loading a libstdc++.dll from somewhere on your path that isn't compatible with the one used by your compiler.

The last comment from @AlanBirtles is my guess. Check the folders of your OS PATH environment variable for the dll runtime files for your compiler. It can be caused by other instances of MinGW or even other software that was compiled using MinGW. The problem is when when the OS looks for dlls it doesn't know anything about compatibility. It just searches for a dll of the same name and when it finds one it loads it. For the PATH environment variable the OS searches in order from the top or left of the PATH to the bottom or right.

@drescherjm thank you. I did as you asked. The error is gone now.

Great! I hope you learned some trouble shooting steps along the way and have a better understanding how it all works..
